# Convert Jira issue files into CSV

Tags: jira

After screwing up with our server, we somehow fixed our project in Jira. But we've lost newest issues and some settings.

We now have files of this issues (`folder with issue number->thumbs folder with attachments and two files of unknown extension`)

[image: There's how it looks like]

I've searched how to convert these files into CSV in order to import it via Jira itself, but couldn't find anything yet.

Maybe there is someone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, it was a folder with only attachment files. Nothing about issue itself.